# SQL Server - Trade values from 2 rows

Tags: sql-server

I've created a sports database for a league I play in (Football) and I'm running into a problem. When I originally set up the sacks being stored, I put them for the wrong team. Now, I'm trying to write a query to trade the values of just the sacks and sackyrds, because we have a lot more data in each row besides the sack data.

EDIT: I should note that I have a very large amount of games that this is the case. So a manual update probably isn't going to cut it.

```
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
| fk_eventID |  teamName  | homeAway | sacks | sackyrds |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
|    123     |   London   |    0     |   3   |    9     |
|    123     | St Thomas  |    1     |   2   |    5     |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Is there anything that I can run to have it look like the following? Basically, I need to swap the sacks and sackyrds from Row1 with the values from Row2.

```
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+    
| fk_eventID |  teamName  | homeAway | sacks | sackyrds |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
|    123     |   London   |    0     |   2   |    5     |
|    123     | St Thomas  |    1     |   3   |    9     |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a large number of instances wherein this is an issue your best bet is just a couple of direct updates.

```
Update StatsTable
SET sacks = 2, sackyrds = 5
Where fk_eventID = 123 and teamName = 'St Thomas'

Update StatsTable
SET sacks = 3, sackyrds = 9
Where fk_eventID = 123 and teamName = 'London'
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that I do have a very large amount of instances I need this done for, so the normal switching wouldn't work like above.

Answer (score 0):

A manual update is probably safest. That said,

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Teams(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Team nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Sacks int NOT NULL,
    SackYards int NOT NULL
) 
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Teams] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Teams] ([ID], [Team], [Sacks], [SackYards]) VALUES (1, N'Bears', 5, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Teams] ([ID], [Team], [Sacks], [SackYards]) VALUES (2, N'Chickens', 2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Teams] ([ID], [Team], [Sacks], [SackYards]) VALUES (3, N'ChickenHawks', 10, 10)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Teams] OFF
GO

select * 
from teams ex
join teams new on 
    (ex.Team = 'Bears' and new.Team = 'Chickens')
    or
    (ex.Team = 'Chickens' and new.Team = 'Bears')

update ex
    set Sacks = new.Sacks, SackYards = new.SackYards
from teams ex
join teams new on 
    (ex.Team = 'Bears' and new.Team = 'Chickens')
    or
    (ex.Team = 'Chickens' and new.Team = 'Bears')

select * 
from teams
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach.  Generate your updates statements as strings, then copy and paste those to execute separately...

```
-- Update for away teams
select 'UPDATE [TableName] SET sacks = ' + CAST(T2.sacks as VARCHAR(100)) + ', sackyrds = ' + CAST(T2.sackyrds as VARCHAR(100)) + ' WHERE fk_eventID = ' + CAST(T1.fk_eventID as VARCHAR(100)) + ' AND homeAway = 0'
from [TableName] T1
inner join [TableName] T2 on T1.fk_eventID = T2.fk_eventID and T2.homeAway = 1
where T1.homeAway = 0

union

-- Update for home teams
select 'UPDATE [TableName] SET sacks = ' + CAST(T2.sacks as VARCHAR(100)) + ', sackyrds = ' + CAST(T2.sackyrds as VARCHAR(100)) + ' WHERE fk_eventID = ' + CAST(T1.fk_eventID as VARCHAR(100)) + ' AND homeAway = 1'
from [TableName] T1
inner join [TableName] T2 on T1.fk_eventID = T2.fk_eventID and T2.homeAway = 0
where T1.homeAway = 1
```

The first part selects all away teams (homeAway = 0) and joins to the same table to also get the home row for that event.  It then generates an UPDATE statement for that data.  The union then repeats but for home teams joined to away.

**Note:** I have not tested this script so it's quite possible you may need to fix something in it but hopefully you get the general idea.

I've also made the assumption that for each fk_eventID there is only ever 2 rows (homeAway = 0 or 1).